Using chrome profile in chrome webdriver
This is my setup for a test.
public void setup() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        String userDataPath = "C:\\Users\\Barak\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data";
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + userDataPath);
        options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");        
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

I need to open the driver with the profile so i can use an extension, is that possible?
From what i saw online, this is the way but it is not working right now.
I will appreciate the help.
I want to use a profile of chrome using the webdriver so i can use extension in the session.
